# Use AngularJS scope to Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Trying to access my AngularJS scope variable in Javascript. I can access those values in html with `{{ gettickeritems.dates }}`, but I'd like to use it in data/labels (instead of the current `{!!  $dates !!}`)

html + Javascript:

```
<div ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="gettickersCtrl">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">                     
        <div><canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="600"></canvas></div>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
            var chart = new Chart(ctx, {                            
            type: 'line',                           
            data: {
                labels: {!!  $dates !!} , // <-- How to access gettickeritems.dates here?
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Amount ' ,
                    data: {!!  $prices !!} 
                }]
            });  
        </script>
      </div>
    </div>

{{ gettickeritems.dates }} <!-- This works -->

</div> <!-- ng-controller -->
</div> <!-- ng-app -->
```

AngularJS:

```
var app = angular.module('gettickers',[]);
app.controller('gettickersCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', function($scope, $http, $location){
var urlapigettickers = $location.protocol() + "://" + $location.host() + "/api/gettickers" ;

$http.get(urlapigettickers).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.gettickeritems = data.gettickers;
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log("No data found..");
  });
}]);
```

Comment: you can't. Keep the entire logic (for charts) within the controller

Comment: Just write the logic in controller. Should work as expected and testable code.

Comment: Ok, not too sure how to implement that though. Any examples (without using another dependency)

Answer (score 0):

you can use it by below code,

```
<script>
            var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
            var chart = new Chart(ctx, {                            
            type: 'line',                           
            data: {
                labels: angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-controller="gettickersCtrl"]')).scope().gettickeritems.dates ,
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Amount ' ,
                    data: angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-controller="gettickersCtrl"]')).scope().gettickeritems.prices 
                }]
            });  
        </script>
```

you can learn more about this from below link:
https://coderwall.com/p/smkwhg/access-scope-outside-of-angularjs

Comment: I tried `labels: angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-controller="gettickersCtrl"]')).scope().gettickeritems.dates` but get the following error `TypeError: angular.element(...).scope(...) is undefined` I'm able to access the value in html with `{{ gettickeritems.dates }}`

Comment: try to debug and see that you find angular object or not

Comment: refer link which I have given at last

Comment: have you got your problem?

Comment: No, tried this `var myData = angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-controller="gettickersCtrl"]')).scope();` to test and myData is undefined. Interesting. Thought it should work, but doesn't.

Comment: first try to get angular object in your script if it got then try to get document.querySelector if both works then it should work.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but I'll keep playing with this. thanks